# как вывести двумерный ступенчатый массив PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть следующая задача:

Создать массив из 10 элементов, каждый из которых будет представлять из себя массив с числами на которые делится соответствующее число из массива (К примеру если массив имеет следующую структуру [8, 21, 6, 2, 6, 7, 9, 2, 1, 10], то первый элемент в массиве будет массивом, состоящим из элементов [1, 2, 4, 8], второй [1, 3, 7, 21] и т.д.)

Решение моё:

```
//входной массив
$array = [8, 21, 6, 2, 6, 7, 9, 2, 1, 10];

//заполнение массива делящимися на элементы входного массива числами

for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++){
     for($j=1; $j<=$array[$i]; $j++){
        if($array[$i]%$j==0){
            $store_array[] = $j;

        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос: как теперь вывести на экран двумерный массив, чтобы было вот так:
1-массив: 1, 2, 4, 8
2-массив: 1, 3, 7, 21
....... и т.д

Answer (score 0):

ты не правильно строишь массив

`$array = [8, 21, 6, 2, 6, 7, 9, 2, 1, 10];`

//заполнение массива делящимися на элементы входного массива числами

```
for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++){
   for($j=1; $j<=$array[$i]; $j++){
        if($array[$i]%$j==0){
            $store_array[$i][] = $j;
        }
    }
 }
```

а вот так выводить массив

```
foreach ($store_array as $key => $item){
    echo 'Массив ' . $key . ' = ';
    foreach ($item as $sub_item){
     echo $sub_item . ' ';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: значения `1` и `$array[$i]` можно добавить к результату без всяких проверок, а сам перебор следует ограничить значением `$array[$i] / 2`